# Dealing with negative exponents without using POW in C++

Tags: c++, math, syntax

Hey guys i'm working through a book and i'm little baffled with the sub objective of the following question..

Powers of numbers can be calculated by multiplying the number by itself for as many times as the value of the exponent. For example, 2 raised to the power 4 can be calculated by multiplying 2 by itself 4 times to get 16. Write a program that:
1. inputs a double as the base number and an int as the exponent;

```
double base, ans = 0;
int exponent;

cout << "This program will calculate the power of any number that you enter.." << endl;
cout << "Please enter your base number" << endl;
cin >> base;
cout << "Thank you" << endl;
cout << "Please enter the Exponent" << endl;
cin >> exponent;
```

2. multiplies the base number by itself using a loop that repeats for the number of times in the int;

   ```
   while (exponent != 0)
   {
       ans = ans + (base * base);
       --exponent;
   }
   ```
3. outputs the exponential value calculated.

   ```
   cout << "The answer is " << ans << endl;
   ```

Use an if statement for the special case where the output is 1 if the int value is 0.

```
if (exponent == 0)
{
    cout << "The answer is " << 1 << " because the exponent value entered was 0" << endl;
}
```

For a more challenging version, deal with the case where the exponent is negative.
(this is where my problem sits.. i cant get the working without using POW)
here is what i tried:

```
else if (exponent < 0)
{
    ans = pow(base, exponent);
    /*
    ans++;
    while (exponent != 0)
    {
        ans = 1/(ans + (base * base));
        ++exponent;
    }
    */
    cout << "The answer is " << ans << endl;
}
```

I did some searching online and found this: "To represent a negative exponent. All you have to do is divide 1 over the positive exponent. Ex: 6^-2 = 1/(6^2)."

and this: "Well that's because in C++ the ^ is the bitwise xor operator...you will need to use the pow() in order to do it."

any help or comments are welcome
thanks in advance

Comment: "I did some searching online and found this" why not use this approach? from a maths point of view `6 ^ (-2)` indeed is the same as `1/(6^2)`.

Comment: You need to do `1/(6^2)` in two steps: First you calculate `6^2`, that is `6` to the power of `2`, the way you normally calculate with positive exponents. Then you take the result and use as divisor. The usage of `^`  is just how it's commonly written, it doesn't mean the bitwise XOR operator.

Comment: "here is what i tried:" do you refer to the code that is inside the comment? Not clear why you `ans++`, or how you arrive at  `ans = 1/(ans + (base * base));`

Comment: That's what i tried here but i guess i have the syntax wrong or something ans = 1/(ans + (base * base));

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 i initialized ans with a value of 0.. so i cant use it to multiply of divide

Comment: You need to do the division *after* you calculated the result for a positive exponent. You should not do the division in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a matter of conventions and definition that in mathematics (ie `^` is exponentation here)

```
a ^ (-b) = 1 / (a^b)
```

Hence if you know how to compute `(a^b)` you just need to take the reciprocal to get the desired result. Something along the line of:

```
double my_pow(double a,double b) {
      if (b < 0) return 1.0 / pow(a,std::abs(b));
      else return pow(a,b);
}
```

As I understood you, you want to write your own implementation of `pow`, so this is just to illustrate how to use a `pow` that works for positive exponents also with negative ones.

Concerning your code, I dont see how this

> ```
> while (exponent != 0)
> {
>     ans = ans + (base * base);
>     --exponent;
> }
> ```

can be correct.

> multiplies the base number by itself using a loop that repeats for the number of times in the int;

No. Thats not really what that loop is doing.

I'd rather expect to see something like this

```
ans = 1;
for (int i=0; i< exponent;++i) {
    ans *= base;
}
```

**PS**: If you do actually not want to write your own, you can use [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow). It can be used with negative exponents.

Comment: isn't this just a self written POW function using cmath POW?

Comment: @SmokeyVanDenBerg please read carefully or reload the page, or both ;). I wrote "As I understood you, you want to write your own implementation of pow, so this is just to illustrate how to use a pow that works for positive exponents also with negative ones."

Comment: for (int i=0; i< exponent;++i) {
    ans *= base;
} was what i tried the first time but noticed now i made a stupid mistake with the loop so it didn't function correctly.. i uses i++ instead id ++i let me try again ill get back to you

Comment: @SmokeyVanDenBerg `++i` vs `i++` should not make any difference here

Comment: isn't ++i going to add 1 before using i, and i++ add 1 after using i?

Comment: @SmokeyVanDenBerg correct, but in the loop increment the result of the expression `++i` is not used for anything

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double raise_to_power(double, double);

main(){
double x;
double y;

cout<<"plz enter the number";
cin>>x;
cout<<"plz enter the power";
cin>>y;

cout<<"The power of a number is "<<raise_to_power(x,y);

    
}

double raise_to_power(double number, double power){
double i;
double result;
result=1.0;

for(i=-1; i>=power && power!=0; i-- ){
    
    result=result*(1/number);
    
 }
 
 
 return result;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Hate to pick on this but why no whitespace? Do people really write code like this? **result=result*(1/number);**